# Maven Release Plugin and SVN commit error

Tags: svn, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I am new to this Maven. Currently I am working on SVN. I am facing a problem when I am trying to apply " mvn release:prepare " command. It shows error, as below

Error :--

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:03.733s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 02 10:17:17 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:prepare (default-cli) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: Commit failed (details follow):
[ERROR] svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
[ERROR] Valid Radar/Espresso number is not given with commit.
[ERROR] Provide Radar number as rdar://12345678 OR Provide Espresso number as <exp2://Ticket/12345678>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Please help me.I have already checked out the location to my local.And then I am applying this command and its unable to submit to SVN.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From

> Provide Radar number as rdar://12345678 OR Provide Espresso number as

I think your svn server require you to commit with an exact format of message. So I think you should try with one of the above formats: `rdar://12345678` or `<exp2://Ticket/12345678>`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But, how to pass that parameter with command.I have already tried -Drdar=12345678.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try `Tip #1 - Change Commmit Comment` at http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2008/10/more-tips-on-using-maven2-release.html . Good luck :D